# How to swipe to view a new page in TitaniumStudio Alloy Framework Development

Tags: titanium, swipe, titanium-alloy

I am new at this so apologies if this is a silly question... I am developing an app in Titanium using the Alloy Framework, and trying to create functionality such that I can have one page with a title, some text and an image, then I swipe to see a different title, text and image... sort of like an eBook. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

So far all I have managed to do is create a table with the list of all the headings and I can click each one to see the content, but then must go back to get into the next page, which is a bit cumbersome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Titanium ScrollableView is your friend

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView

Thanks